# PHP While Input Field -> DB

Tags: php

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I have a while that creates a form for every row inside my table. Now I want to edit a field and change the data from the DB with the one from the field.

```
function Grades($id,$sem){
    echo "<h3>Grades - Sem $sem</h3>";
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id, grade, subject, date, sem
        FROM grades
        WHERE id_student = :id AND
        sem = :sem");
    $sth->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $sth->bindParam(":sem", $sem);
    $sth->execute();
    while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<form action='students.php?change-students' method='post'>";
        echo "<br>Subject ".$result['subject']." Grade ".$result['grade']." Date ".$result['date']." Sem ".$result['sem']."<br>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='grade' value='$result[grade]'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }      

    if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
        echo $_POST['grade'];
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE grades
            SET grade = :grade
            WHERE id_student = :id AND
            sem = :sem");
        $sth->bindParam(":grade", $_POST['grade']);
        $sth->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $sth->bindParam(":sem", $sem);
        $sth->execute();   
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make that name="grade" unique and use it in if isset. Of course I could change name="$result[id]" but I don't know how to use inside isset($_POST['$result['id']).

Thank you

Comment: Careful... use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML, to ensure you generate valid HTML and prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Thank you ... I will change my code

Comment: You're trying to make that one function handle everything. don't do that. One function to build the form. One function to handle the updates. And one function to bring it all together and in the darkness bind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following might help,

simply pass the grades id as hidden field in your form,

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$result[id]'>";
```

and while updating

```
if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
   $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE grades
                  SET grade = :grade
                  WHERE id= :id // this will be your hidden post id(i.e. $_POST['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<input type='text' name=".( isset($_POST[$result['id'])?$_POST[$result['id']):"grade")."value='$result[grade]'>";
```

Or better:

```
$tGrade = isset($_POST[$result['id'])? $_POST[$result['id']):"grade";
echo "<input type='text' name=".$tGrade."value='$result[grade]'>";
```